# How can i change content of <li> every x seconds from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make ***li*** list, where jQuery will every 2 second change content. Something like news from games.
Problem is only at first cycle. At first cycle will skip second item in **array**. Second cycle and next are okay.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            var pages = ["<li class='active'><a href='#'>Hello</a></li>", "<li class='active'><a href='#'>Hello2</a></li>", "<li class='active'><a href='#'>Hello3</a></li>"]
 var index = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#ul_news").empty().append(pages[index]);
        index++;
        if (index >= pages.length){
         index = 0;
        }
        setInterval(function(){
         $(".active").empty().append(pages[index]);
        }, 2000);
    }, 2000);

});
```

```css
#ul_news{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left:100px;
 z-index: 20;
}
#ul_news li{
 z-index: 20;
 color: black;
 list-style: none;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.non_active{
 z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs-cz">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="ul_news">
  <!--<li class="active">aho j2</li>
  <li class="non_active1">ahoj3</li>
  <li class="non_active2">ahoj4</li>
  <li class="non_active3">ahoj5</li>-->
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you've confused [**`setInterval`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) with [**`setTimeout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Because `setInterval` executes a *method* repeatedly (unless it's stopped with [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)), you don't have to nest another `setInterval` within the *method* it executes:

```js
var pages = ["<li class='active'><a href='#'>Hello</a></li>", "<li class='active'><a href='#'>Hello2</a></li>", "<li class='active'><a href='#'>Hello3</a></li>"]
var index = 0;
// just a bit of caching:
var news = $("#ul_news");
setInterval(function() {
  news.html(pages[index]);
  index++;
  if (index >= pages.length){
    index = 0;
  }
}, 2000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs-cz">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="ul_news">
  <!--<li class="active">aho j2</li>
  <li class="non_active1">ahoj3</li>
  <li class="non_active2">ahoj4</li>
  <li class="non_active3">ahoj5</li>-->
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

---

As a side note, you don't need to use `.empty().append()`. You can do the same with just single method [**`html()`**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Thank you. .empty().append() i saw on different website. Thank you for your reply.